# I want a facebook share button that share specific data on user's timeline?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to working with facebook APIs, but i want a facebook share button on my website which share that specific data on user's timeline after log in to facebook. I have already read some documents on that and make a page for testing purpose on my localhost. But there is a problem 
the page is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<script>
function fbs_click(){
    u=location.href;
    t=document.title;
    d='param kumar';
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'t='+encodeURIComponent(t)+'&d'+encodeURIComponent(d),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
    return false;
 }
</script>
<body>
<div>
   <h2>Some content of my website pages..</h2>
</div>
<div id="fb">
   If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the same tag on            your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   <a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://localhost/paramRND/FbShare.php" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"> Share on FB</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the share on Fb button, after log in to Facebook it shows a blank page.
Can any one help me out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your url `//localhost/paramRND/FbShare.php` it will not work for it.add url which is live.

OR
You can make your local machine accessible by using [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me/) . You'll need to (temporarily) change some URLs used in your app code / html so links point to the temporary domain, but at least facebook can reach your machine.

Comment: You mean to say that if I try the same with any live url. it will work?

Comment: If u have right code..or you can easily create a button here [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)

Comment: where you are strucked ?